# Please rename [winterbash-leaderboard] to [winter-bash-leaderboard]

Tags: discussion, meta, retag-request

Note the tag [winterbash-leaderboard](/questions/tagged/winterbash-leaderboard).

All of the other Winter Bash tags are `winter-bash*`.

Can this tag please be changed to [winter-bash-leaderboard](/questions/tagged/winter-bash-leaderboard) to be consistent?

(I grok that it was probably created that way to keep it under 25 characters, but as that is no longer the limit for tag names, it would be nice if it matched the others.)

Comment: There are just 4 questions. Couldn't you just go ahead and change them yourself?

Comment: @muru: No, because I can't create `winter-bash-leaderboard` while `winterbash-leadersboard` exists, since they only differ by a hyphen. I'd have to remove `winterbash-leaderboard`, wait for the system to delete the unused tag, then, create and apply `winter-bash-leaderboard`. That'd look too much like vandalism.

Comment: not if you do it just around when empty tags are removed (4:00 UTC?) and put an short explanation in the edit summary